# PWA Not Opening Up Rear Camera While Using Capacitor/PWA-ELements Ionic Angular App

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

Using Capacitor and PWA-Elements, we are clicking photo on mobile device as per the following code

```
  if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Camera')) {
    this.fileinput.nativeElement.click();
    return;
  }
  else {

    const image = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 20,
      allowEditing: false,
      direction: CameraDirection.Rear,
      correctOrientation: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      source: CameraSource.Camera
    }).then((image) => {
      this.imgBase64List.push(image.base64String);
      this.imgBase64ListDisplay.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + image.base64String);
      // localStorage.setItem(this.TsList.TSNo+ "GpInImageBase64", JSON.stringify(this.imgBase64List));
      this.storeImage();
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.showToast(error)
    });

    /* this.imgBase64List.push(image.base64String);
    this.imgBase64ListDisplay.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + image.base64String);
    // localStorage.setItem(this.TsList.TSNo+ "GpInImageBase64", JSON.stringify(this.imgBase64List));
  
    this.storeImage(); */

  }
```

While **Camera Direction is always rear** but it **always open up front camera** in PWA where as it works perfect as native app(apk)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @Josh No, not yet